# what is the difference between 2 similar queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I was expecting identical outputs but when I ran them separately, got different outputs, can someone explain the differences please? Thank you!

The first is:

```
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE Price > 20
```

The second is:

```
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE Price > SOME (SELECT Price FROM Products WHERE Price > 20);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF7dR.png)

Comment: Consider the case one row only, with price = 21.

Comment: "Go to the shop, and get a loaf of bread. If they have eggs, get 6". When asked why I came home with 6 loaves of bread, I said "they had eggs"

Comment: Might it be more clear if it's written as `SELECT * FROM products WHERE price > (SELECT MIN(price) FROM products WHERE price > 20)` ? Find the minimum price greater than 20, then find all the products greater than that minimum? It's different to "find all products with price greater than 20"

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The table didn't have and price 20<value>21. However, the  first returned 37 records while the second returned 35 records

Comment: OK, so which 2 rows are missing and what are their prices? Also, took a while to find it but: http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2009/08/all-any-and-some-three-stooges.html - why we don't use ALL/ANY ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_any2&ss=-1

I think I have reached the answer.
The first query will return all records where the prices' values are greater than 20.
The second query will return all records where the prices' values are 2 steps greater than 20. So, it will ignore the following prices 20 and  21 twice.

Answer (score 2):

The second query will exclude the minimum result of the first query.

If, for example, 23 is the lowest price greater than 20, then the second query will only look for results with a price greater than 23, and so not include that row (and any others with a price of 23.)

Comment: Thank you Willem for your contribution.
However, the output of the query included prices of 21.05, 21.35 and 21.5 so it did not exclude the minimum results of the first query.

Comment: @MathsandCodes What is the minimum result of the first query? We may be able to diagnose your problem better if we have sample data that reproduces the issue. If the result sets are small enough for the two queries, simply adding that to your question would be very helpful.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_any2&ss=-1

I was exploring the (SOME) logical operator at the above link. You can explore the table yourself in there. 

With regard to my question, I think I have reached the answer. 
The first query will return all records where the prices' values are greater than 20.
The second query will return all records where the prices' values are 2 steps greater than 20. So, it will ignore the following prices 20, 21 twice.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion part is the some operator in your query.

```
Suppose using greater than ( >) with SOME means 
greater than at least one value.
```

That's how the some operator works.
For better understanding
https://www.w3resource.com/sql/special-operators/sql_some.php